# Modificadores de acesso

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

É errado afirmar que os modificadores de acesso controlam os atributos e os métodos de uma classe , evitando a inconsistência nos valores e nos objetos ?

Comment: Sim, é errado afirmar isso.

Comment: É errado, inclusive porque os modificadores de acesso são atributos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/269089/101

Comment: Sim, é errado porque modificadores de acesso não têm relação alguma com consistência de dados, mas sim com visibilidade. Modificadores de acesso bem utilizados ajudam no encapsulamento de suas classes e métodos, bem como no polimorfismo e na própria organização do código.